# How to change poll rate of usb "gamepad" drum controller

Tags: usb, udev, hid

I'm trying to increase the USB poll rate of my ION IED05 drum controller to decrease the latency when striking toms. This drum controller is actually behaving like a USB gamepad, instead of being a MIDI instrument. Therefore i'm writing a midi proxy.

Let me first give you some information.

I'm getting events from `/dev/input/js0` when striking toms.

I'm running an up-to-date Arch Linux install, with the realtime kernel `Linux instrument 5.4.19-rt11-1-rt #1 SMP PREEMPT_RT Fri, 21 Feb 2020 08:55:59 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

On connecting the controller i get the following dmesg output:

```
[ 3502.121825] usb 2-4.1: new low-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 3502.238814] usb 2-4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=15e4, idProduct=0100, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 3502.238817] usb 2-4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3502.238819] usb 2-4.1: Product: DRUM VDX-150
[ 3502.238820] usb 2-4.1: Manufacturer: DRUM VDX-150
[ 3502.257116] input: DRUM VDX-150 DRUM VDX-150 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4/2-4.1/2-4.1:1.0/0003:15E4:0100.000D/input/input44
[ 3502.257407] hid-generic 0003:15E4:0100.000D: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Joystick [DRUM VDX-150 DRUM VDX-150] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4.1/input0
```

The kernel has this to say about the device:

```
instrument# cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | grep DRUM -B3 -A3
T:  Bus=02 Lev=02 Prnt=03 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 11 Spd=1.5  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=15e4 ProdID=0100 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=DRUM VDX-150
S:  Product=DRUM VDX-150
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   8 Ivl=10ms
```

USB device information:

```
instrument# lsusb -vd 15e4:0100                     

Bus 002 Device 011: ID 15e4:0100 Numark 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x15e4 Numark
  idProduct          0x0100 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 DRUM VDX-150
  iProduct                2 DRUM VDX-150
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0022
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      86
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
```

At the moment the drumkit is polled every 8ms (i believe 10 is interpreted as 8 by the kernel?), as can be seen from `Ivl=10ms`

Upon [researching](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_polling_rate) if found that i could force the poll rate, i've set the usbhid.jspoll parameter like so:

```
instrument# cat /etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf
options usbhid jspoll=1
```

Which seems to be picked up:

```
instrument# cat /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/jspoll 
1
```

But this parameter does not seem to change anything about the poll rate.

I'm testing all this with [gilrs](https://crates.io/crates/gilrs), as i'm creating a [midi proxy](https://github.com/Spunge/forex/blob/master/src/main.rs) for this drumkit, and the shortest duration i'm seeing between events is 8ms.

I've tried everything i could come up with and i don't know what to try next..

How do i increase the poll rate of this device?

Answer (score 0):

That's because bInterval it's inherent to the USB Device, it's a spec and you cannot change that unless you are programming the Device itself. You are doing well by decreasing OS poll rate tho, it helps a little in your case.

You can read more about input lag at https://inputlag.science/controller